# Can solvable Lie groups have maximal subgroups?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Many interesting manifolds can be expressed as $ G/H $ for $ G $ a Lie group and $ H $ a maximal closed subgroup. Examples include the projective spaces $ \mathbb{C}P^n \cong SU_n/U_{n-1} $ where $ U_{n-1} $ is maximal for $ n \geq 3 $, and $ \mathbb{R}P^n \cong SO_n/O_{n-1} $, again $ O_{n-1} $ is maximal for $ n \geq 3 $. Another example is the Poincare homology sphere $ SO_3(\mathbb{R})/A_5 $.

Solvmanifolds provide many interesting examples of manifolds, especially of torus bundles over tori (a solvmanifold is a manifold of the form $ G/H $ for $ G $ a solvable Lie group).

The examples I list above for manifolds $ G/H $, $ H $ maximal, all the have the property that $ G $ is semisimple (indeed simple).

This leads me to wonder about maximal closed subgroups $ H $ of solvable Lie groups $ G $. Do they even exist?

Let $ G $ be a connected Lie group.

If $ G $ is abelian then certainly $ G $ does not have any maximal closed subgroups. Does the same hold for $ G $ solvable?

comment (inspired by the comment from
Eero Hakavuori): Let $ G' $ be the commutator subgroup of $ G $. Let
$$
Ab: G \to G/G'
$$
be the abelianization map. If $ H $ is a maximal closed subgroup of $ G $ then we must have
$$
Ab(H)=G/G'
$$
because if $ Ab(H) $ was properly contained then $ Ab(H) $ would be a maximal closed subgroup of the connected abelian group $ G/G' $ which is impossible. In particular that implies that $ H $ does not contain $ G' $ (because if $ Ab(H)=G/G' $
and $ H $ contained $ G' $ that would imply that $ H $ is all of $ G $, contradicting maximality).

Update: A thorough answer is given by Ycor in the cross post to MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433142/can-solvable-connected-lie-groups-have-maximal-subgroups/433144?noredirect=1#comment1115468_433144 a second answer by LSpice,  supplementing his first answer, can also be found there.

Update: Recall that $ G $ is always a connected Lie group.

If $ G $ is nilpotent then there does not exist any maximal proper closed subgroup (proved in the original answer of LSpice).

If $ G $ is non-nilpotent then there does exist some maximal proper closed subgroup. We prove this with two cases.

If the non-nilpotent group $ G $ is moreover non-solvable then we appeal to basically a Levi decomposition. $ Lie(G) $ can be written as
$$
Lie(G)= \mathfrak{g}_{solv} \rtimes \mathfrak{g}_{ss}
$$
Let $ G_{solv} $ be a maximal solvable closed connected subgroup of $ G $ corresponding to the Lie subalgebra $ \mathfrak{g}_{solv} $. Let $ G_{ss} $ be a maximal semisimple closed connected subgroup of $ G $, corresponding to the Lie subalgebra $ \mathfrak{g}_{ss} $. Pick $ H_{max} $ to be a maximal proper closed subgroup of $ G_{ss} $ (there are lots of fairly well known maximal closed subgroups of semisimple groups). Then the group generated by $ G_{solv} $ and $ H_{max} $ should be roughly $ G_{solv} \rtimes H_{max} $ and should be a maximal proper closed subgroup of $ G $.

For the case that the non-nilpotent group $ G $ is solvable, then apply the answer from Ycor (accepted below) which shows that a solvable non-nilpotent Lie group $ G $ must have a quotient which is one of the four solvable non-nilpotent subgroups of
$$
AGL_1(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}^* \ltimes \mathbb{C}
$$
that Ycor lists below. In that case there is a maximal proper closed subgroup of the quotient so we can pullback through the quotient map to get a maximal proper closed subgroup of the solvable non-nilpotent Lie group $ G $.

This proves the claim, from Ycor's comment, that a connected Lie group $ G $ has a maximal proper closed subgroup if and only if $ G $ is non-nilpotent.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: +1 Thanks for making the edits to your question. Now you have a well-researched and well-explained question which meets the guidelines for our site.

Comment: Can you not just repeat any subgroup-extension argument for the abelian case by considering quotients of terms from the derived series?

Comment: @EeroHakavuori ya that's my intuition but I'm not quite sure how to turn that into a proof. But definitely thinking along those lines shows that a maximal subgroup never contains the commutator subgroup, which is kind of interesting. I added that as an update to my question.

Comment: What do you mean by maximal closed subgroup? Isn't G always a closed subgroup of itself (and therefore the only maximal one)?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle Ya that would make the question trivial. I mean maximal among the proper closed subgroups.

Comment: Doesn't the existence of maximal proper closed subgroups follow trivially from the fact that any increasing chain of subgroups has finite lenght (since the dimension must increase at each step)? You say that there are no maximal proper closed subgroups if $G$ is abelian, but what about $G=\mathbb{R}^n$, $H=\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Comment: @AntoineLabelle dimension does not strictly increase. Take $ \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R} $ between $ \mathbb{R} $ and $ 
 \mathbb{R}^2 $

Comment: Oh I see, you don't require $H$ to be connected. That makes sense.

Comment: Yup yup if we require everything to be connected then all this can be decided at the level of Lie algebras which makes it all much easier (and in that case you are of course right that one could argue on strictly increasing dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the etiquette for answering [cross-posted questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433142/can-solvable-connected-lie-groups-have-maximal-subgroups).  I also posted this answer on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433144).  If it is not appropriate to post it here, then I am happy to delete it.  See also my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433238) on MO discussing certain special soluble groups, and @YCor's more general [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/433250) on MO that handles the general soluble case.

A connected, <s>soluble</s> nilpotent Lie group $G$ has no maximal proper, closed subgroup.  (Thanks to @YCor for [pointing out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433142/can-solvable-connected-lie-groups-have-maximal-subgroups/433144#comment1115148_433144) on MathOverflow, with a counterexample, that my original claim was incorrect.)

We proceed by induction on the dimension of $G$.  If the dimension is $0$, then $G$ is trivial, and we are done; so suppose that the dimension is positive, and hence that $\operatorname Z(G)^\circ$ is a positive-dimensional subgroup of $G$.

Suppose that $H$ is a maximal proper, closed subgroup of $G$.  If $H$ contains $\operatorname Z(G)^\circ$, then $H/{\operatorname Z(G)}^\circ$ is a maximal proper, closed subgroup of $G/{\operatorname Z(G)}^\circ$, which is a contradiction.  Therefore, $H$ is a proper subgroup of $H\cdot\operatorname Z(G)^\circ$.  By maximality, we have that $H\cdot\operatorname Z(G)^\circ$ is dense in $G$.  (It seems plausible that $H\cdot\operatorname Z(G)^\circ$ is already closed, but I do not know how to prove it.)  Thus, for every pair of elements $g, g' \in G$, we have sequences $((h_n, z_n))_n$ and $((h_n', z_n'))_n$ in $H \times \operatorname Z(G)^\circ$ whose images under the multiplication map $H \times \operatorname Z(G)^\circ \to G$ converge to $g$ and $g'$.  Then the sequence $([h_n z_n, h_n'z_n^{\prime\,{-1}}])_n$ equals $([h_n, h_n'])_n$, hence lies in $H$; and converges to $[g, g']$, which therefore belongs to $H$.  Then $H$ contains the derived subgroup of $G$, which, as you have observed, is a contradiction.